# cypress how to get the div id of the index list and compare if its true

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

Hi I am trying to loop over all the 'li' value in my page. If its locator is equal to the value am searching i want it to skip and go over to the next index value and continue

```
<div id="images">

 <ul>
  <li class= image> </li>
  <li class= video> </li> 
  <li class= image>  </li>
  <li class= image>  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

So here when its video I want to skip it and when its image it can continue with the validations.

```
cy.get(image.ALL_ITEMS).should('exist').its('length').then(($lengthAllImgs) => {
        for (var $img = 0; $img < $lengthAllImgs - 1;$img++;) {
if(cy.get(image.ALL_ITEMS).eq(img).get('li').contains('video')){
break;
}
else {
}
}
```

I understand the above if formation is wrong but how do i change it to work to make the if and else work inside for loop

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `.image` class to your selector to filter out the video:

```js
cy.get('div.images')
  .find('li.image')
  .each($image => {
    ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `cy.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) to iterate through all yielded results from a Cypress query command. Using this, we can easily determine the characteristics of the element and determine what action to take. From your example, it looks like the attribute we want to check if the class, so we can use [JQuery's `.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```js
cy.get('li').each(($li) => { // generic selector to select all items
  if ($li.hasClass('video')) { // use JQuery's `.hasClass()` to determine if the element is video or image
    // code to execute if element is a video class
  } else {
    // code to execute if element is an image class
  }
});
```